# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [23038, 7680] in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I tried to run the following code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2 )
classifier.fit(X_train, y_test)
```

and the error I'm getting is:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2 )
classifier.fit(X_train, y_test)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-47-60c527e5ec72>", line 3, in <module>
classifier.fit(X_train, y_test)

File "C:\Users\rahul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 765, in fit
X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)

File "C:\Users\rahul\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 583, in check_X_y
check_consistent_length(X, y)

File "C:\Users\rahul\Anaconda3\lib\site-pac kages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 204, in check_consistent_length
" samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [23038, 7680]
```

Anyone knows what should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are fitting the training test, with the wrong labels (i.e. the test labels). Please use the training labels

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors =5, metric = 'minkowski', p = 2 )
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
classifier.predict(X_test)
```